# Index, Match function based off multiple criteria

Tags: indexing, match

"Dashboard" [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lHxlQ.png)

Weekly Calls: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nS2UZ.png)

Formula: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g1y8q.png)

I am trying to create a dashboard that allows me to pick a week and a company name and then it would pull the appropriate "jobs booked" number. I am using an Index Match formula that I have used for other things and it doesnt seem to be working.

I also would like to take this one step further and eventually narrow it down to specific business units that are in column B (Weekly Calls) and Row 4 (Sheet1).

Formula attached above.

Comment: Sounds like you need a helper column where you combine the week and company name together and match by that.

Comment: @solarmike can you expand on that? Sorry not completely sure what you mean by that.